# How to make liferay generate https urls for its links instead of http?

Tags: java, nginx, https, liferay

In older version of Liferay this was set in the control panel.

This manifests as a problem where we make the HTTPS connection to application, but Application start executed, but the browser to load unprotected data, which the browser reports as an error.

Can I use this (Switch - relocate) for (changing from HTTP to HTTPS)?

My Local application opening in HTTP. I need to migrating to HTTPS URL.

How can I use properties file to configure. `ex: relocate http://ab.qa.app.us/ https://ab.qa.app.us/`?

Comment: Do you have this issue on local liferay and/or server? What is your platform locally and/or on the server? You mentioned nginx in the tags. If so you may have to configure it differently that I mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly and this issue is targeted to your local lifeary bundle, you will need to do the following steps to configure HTTPS on Tomcat and Liferay. Please clarify if you have already done these steps and still running into issues:

- Enable HTTPS with a self-signed certificate on Tomcat (follow steps in the Liferay wiki article below)
- Add the following property to the portal-ext.properties file.

> company.security.auth.requires.https=true

Please refer to the article for more information: [How to configure HTTPS in Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+configure+https+feature)

Comment: As far as I understand the intention of the OP (which is difficult due to his format), he doesn't ask how to change to HTTPS when authenticating. But he has the problem that all links are HTTP, even if the portal is opened using HTTPS. Which usually has something to do with proper configuration of connectors.